# What do the values in glm::ortho<T>() mean?

Tags: c++, opengl, projection, glm-math

The documentation lists it as

```
detail::tmat4x4<T> glm::gtc::matrix_transform::ortho    (   T const &   left,
        T const &   right,
        T const &   bottom,
        T const &   top,
        T const &   zNear,
        T const &   zFar 
    )
```

With little  more information. My hypothesis is that in a cartesian plane the recangle of coordinates:

(right, top), (top, left), (bottom, left), (bottom, right)

Defines the recangle into which we are to project our objects.

And zNear, zFar describe clipping points (anything outside of these points is saturated and mapped to either 1 or -1)

Am I correct?

Comment: `glm::ortho` works at most like old fixed-pipeline (OpenGL < 3) [glOrtho](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml). Read that link for info about your question.